# Error al sumar en mysql. SELECT IF

Tags: mysql, select, condiciones

De antemano, muchas gracias por la ayuda,

Estoy realizando un programa para llevar contabilidad con java y mysql,

el problema que actualmente tengo es que al tratar de realizar una consulta mysql no me arroja las sumas de los datos correctamente.

Tengo dos bases de datos una se llama CatalogoCuentas y otra diario,

En el catalogo de cuentas tengo el numero de cuenta y los generales de las cuentas en el diario tengo lo movimientos de contabilidad ambas relacionadas por el numero de cuenta.

El problema es que cuando realizo la sumatoria, no me espeta el periodo (mes) y me suma todo

Estos son los datos almacenados en diario:
[image: Estos son los datos almacenados en diario]

Este es mi código, pero no se que esta mal

Los primeros dos IF son para sumar las cantidades de años anteriores
Los segundos son para sumar las cantidades que son del mismo año, pero de meses anteriores (pretendo sumar estos dos en java para obtener los saldos iniciales )
y los últimos son para sumar las cantidades del mes actual

```sql
SELECT NumeroCuenta,CatalogoCuentas.NombreCuenta,TipoCuenta, Naturaleza, 
IF(YEAR(Fecha) < 2019, SUM(Cargos),0) AS SiCargosA,
IF(YEAR(Fecha) < 2019, SUM(Abonos),0) AS SiAbonosA, 
IF(YEAR(Fecha) = 2019 AND Periodo <3, SUM(Cargos),0) AS SiCargos, 
IF(YEAR(Fecha) = 2019 AND Periodo <3, SUM(Abonos),0) AS SiAbonos, 
IF((periodo = 3 AND YEAR(Fecha) = 2019), SUM(Cargos),0) AS Cargo, 
IF((periodo = 3 AND YEAR(Fecha) = 2019), SUM(Abonos),0) AS Abono 
FROM rfc.CatalogoCuentas 
LEFT JOIN rfc.diario 
ON NumeroCuenta = NumCuenta 
GROUP BY NumeroCuenta 
ORDER BY NumeroCuenta ASC;
```

y este es el resultado que me arroja

[image: resultado sql]

Espero puedan ayudarme,  saludos

Answer (score 0):

Pon la condición dentro de la función de agregación:

```
sum(if(year(Fecha)<2019,Cargos,0)) SiCargosA
```

A esto se le llama *agregación condicional*.

Comment: Muchas Gracias me funciono muy bien